# How to fetch data on Gatsby build rather than component mount?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

React application serving as frontend for Markdown content pushed next to the code.

Said Markdown is run against a specific RegExp and replace matches as the Markdown is rendered into [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/) components with data fetched from an external API.

The issue is that the application will fetch and replace on every refresh of the page. I'm trying to do those steps as I build the application, rather than on run.

Here are the relevant files:

- `gatsby-node.js`
  https://github.com/angrybacon/doomsday-wiki/blob/ff0ab5c82e/gatsby-node.js#L35-L39
- `src/components/Page.js`
  https://github.com/angrybacon/doomsday-wiki/blob/ff0ab5c82e/src/components/Page.js#L13
- `src/components/Markdown.js`
  https://github.com/angrybacon/doomsday-wiki/blob/ff0ab5c82e/src/components/Markdown.js#L62-L67
- `src/components/Scryfall.js`
  https://github.com/angrybacon/doomsday-wiki/blob/ff0ab5c82e/src/components/Scryfall.js#L78

Using Gatsby doesn't solve the issue automatically in that when building the components are not mounted and data isn't fetched yet. How can I achieve that?

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/creating-a-source-plugin/

Comment: @ksav How does that help? Please clarify.

Comment: You are talking about sourcing data at build time. The way to do that is with a source plugin.

Comment: @ksav Not entirely true (or I'm misunderstanding the terminology). I can *source* my Markdown content at build time alright. But I need another step that is to instantiate a ReactMarkdown content at build time as well, except that step seems to be run later on.